# Kentico - Editable WebPartZones on children pages?

Tags: templates, master-pages, web-parts, kentico

I added a WebPartZone in the master page at the top pf the master page, this web part zone is a message bar that will display on all the pages but could be different on each page. Is it possible to have a web part zone in the template that is editable on each page? Or is a different way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer no. From the template engine prospective whatever editable in the master - is not editable in its children. All editable web parts/widgets   editable on the master, are not editable in its children.

If you really want to have an editable text in the master and all its children, you probably need to clone and customize web part and form control it is based on. Or create you own web part.

P.S. You can have editable text in your page template so all page that use this template will have this editable text working.

If you can give more details on what kind thing you want to edit would be easier to provide an answer

P.P.S. You can have a work around but it will not be with editable text. You will have to edit message text at the form tab. Would that suits you?

Comment: thank you. Basically I want to display a message web part at the top of the page  but the message can be different on each page, I wanted the zone. One option that I was thinking is to add the web part on the page body on each child then add a container or something to move the message at the top of the page using CSS.

Comment: If you want to display message without editable web part - it is doable:

- You need to create a  master document type that will have text field called `message`.
- Inherit all your document types from this master, so all documents will `have message` field in there form tan.
- then you can drop static text web part on your master template
-

Comment: - . in the text property of the web part  you add macro {%CurrentDocument.GetValue("Message")%}
So web part is in the master but it will display page specific message

Answer (score 0):

You can add the webpart on your master, and use a macro to get the content, like {%CurrentDocument.GetValue("Message")%}, but you have to add a field to each page to store the message in.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing out one more option, if what you want to display changes from page type to page type, you can put a repeater on the master page, put a path of a period (current document), then use macros to set the page type to the current document class name and the transformation to currentdocument.classname+".mastermessage"

Using a macro, then add a transformation "mastermessage" to each page type it will encounter, then you can change the fields and format for each page type.